# Some problems with Materialize CSS

Tags: material-design, materialize

I have some problems to resolve with my website

When I put the min.css in the header, the logo of the navbar is cutted, only on mobile device..? Why?

How to transform some buttons into a dropdown button on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Your question answer is 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FASMaterialize.CSS

This application will resolve your problem.